Calling google cloud functions from google cloud functions
I am trying to fetch some data from the steam API so I can include it into my website as a dataset (JSON) but after updating the code no longer works. I've been trying to debug it for a little while now but the api calls to my get_achievements_for_game dont't resolve if I call it from the get_all_games. I tried calling the get_achievements_for_game function manually and that seemed to work. it just does not work when called from get_all_games.
Could someone with more experience with cloud functions (and back-end) help me out fixing this?
let gameAmount: number = 4;

require('dotenv').config();

export const get_all_games = v2.https.onRequest(
    { cors: false }, (request, response) => {
        let parsedAmount = Number.parseInt(request.params[0]);
        if (!Number.isNaN(parsedAmount)) {
            gameAmount = parsedAmount;
        }
        const url = `https://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=${process.env.API_KEY}&steamid=${process.env.STEAM_ID}&format=json&include_appinfo=true`;
        https.get(url, (res: any) => {
            debugger;
            let data = '';

            res.on('data', (chunk: any) => {
                data += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                try {
                    const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
                    let filteredGames = jsonData.response.games.filter((game: any) => game.playtime_forever > 300);
                    filteredGames.sort((a: any, b: any) => b.playtime_forever - a.playtime_forever);
                    filteredGames = filteredGames.slice(0, gameAmount);

                    const urlBase = `http://${request.headers.host?.toString()}/${process.env.PROJECT_ID}/${process.env.SERVER_ID}/get_achievements_for_game/`;
                    let remainingCalls = gameAmount;
                    for (const achievements of filteredGames) {
                        http.request(urlBase + achievements.appid, { timeout: 100 }, (res2: any) => {
                            let data2 = '';

                            res2.on('data', (chunk2: any) => {
                                data2 += chunk2;
                            });

                            res2.on('end', () => {
                                const playerstats = JSON.parse(data2).playerstats;
                                achievements.current_achievements = playerstats.progress;
                                if (playerstats.achievements !== undefined) {
                                    achievements.total_achievements = playerstats.achievements.length;
                                }

                                remainingCalls--;
                                if (remainingCalls === 0) {
                                    response.status(200).json(filteredGames);
                                }
                            });

                            res2.on('error', (error: any) => {
                                response.status(500).send(error.message);
                            });
                        }).on('error', (error: any) => {
                            response.status(500).send(error.message);
                        });
                    }
                } catch (error: any) {
                    response.status(500).send(error.message);
                }
            });

            res.on('error', (error: any) => {
                response.status(500).send(error.message);
            });
        }).on('error', (error: any) => {
            response.status(500).send(error.message);
        });
    });

//this function is never executed.
export const get_achievements_for_game = v2.https.onRequest(
    { cors: false, }, (request: any, response) => {
        const url = `https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetPlayerAchievements/v1?key=${process.env.API_KEY}&appid=${request.params[0].replace('/', '')}&steamid=${process.env.STEAM_ID}`;
        https.get(url, (res: any) => {
            let data = '';

            res.on('data', (chunk: any) => {
                data += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                let countAchieved: number = 0;

                let jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
                if (jsonData.playerstats.success === true) {
                    for (const achievement of jsonData.playerstats.achievements) {
                        if (achievement.achieved == 1) {
                            countAchieved++;
                        }
                    }
                    jsonData.playerstats.progress = countAchieved;
                }
                response.status(200).json(jsonData);
            });
        }).on('error', (error: any) => {
            response.status(500).send(error.message);
        });
    });


update: 
I revised the entire code and now I have an actual error message to report. Though I don't know why its happening... https://pastebin.com/WQ71vLAL

What do you mean "doesn't trigger"?  Is there an error?  What is it, and which line causes it?  Please edit the question to show your debugging details.

https://pastebin.com/qsQXemhq (so I can add line numbers) on line 31 I am making a request to the second function in my file get_achievements_for_game and passing in the data as parameters so it know what data I am looking for. That call is made, but putting a breakpoint with the chrome tools does not trigger any debugger (on line 74). I had this code working about 2 months ago but I needed to upgrade my cloud functions since they wouldn't compile if I didnt update firebase-functions @DougStevenson

it will be https not http like you have here...const urlBase = `http://${request.headers.host

@smoore4 appearantly not, because when i change it to https it fails instantly and shows me Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:"
